# how to get ios 5.1 into xcode simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

iOS 5.1 was just recently released and I want to test it on my simulator but the highest available is iOS 5.0. I went to the developer centre to download it but all I could find was a list for sdk iOS 5.1 for devices (ipad, iphone, ipad 2 etc etc).

How do I get 5.1 into my simulator?

thanks!

Comment: To elaborate on jayydee3's response, if you are on Lion go to the mac app store to download Xcode. It will come with the latest SDKs. NOTE: you need to have Lion to install Xcode 4.3.1, which is the only version of Xcode with the 5.1 SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install Lion *and* the new Xcode 4.3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... HAS to be Lion?

Comment: thanks for editing fichek. Yes, you need Lion to develop for 5.1. (Also I have seen workarounds, but they are not official and could lead to problems. What they have done is to copy all 5.1 Debugger Files from a Lion XCode installation to a SnowLeopard installation, but i would NOT recommend this)